# MySQL: how to get number of ingreedients of products in final order

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my database:

[image]

I have problem with query, that probably is classic issue in ecommerce.

I have product that have ingredients,
I am selling ingredients of products but what users are adding to cart are products. 
so i.e. 10 products they add to cart, but in cart summary I need to display to them how much ingredients they are buying to create that products.

ie. people are buying ingredients to create 5 bottles of coca cola and 5 bottles of Sprite, and that is what they are adding to cart, system needs to calculate how much total sugar, water, cocacola_ingredient, sprite_ingredient need to be used produce those 5 bottles of coca cola and 5 bottles of sprite

i have table `orderhasproducts` that keeps info how much bottle of coca cola and sprite user ordered

and I have table `producthasingredients` keeping info about how much particular ingredient are in particular product

what i need to do is calculate total number of all ingredients for all products in particular order.

that is my last query, that still doesnt work:

```
SELECT ingredients.name, 

(SELECT SUM(producthasingredients.quantity * product.quantity / 100 * orderhasproducts.numofproducts) 
        FROM producthasingredients INNER JOIN product ON product.id= producthasingredients.id_product 
        WHERE ingredients.id=producthasingredients.id_ingredient )AS totalIngredient

FROM ingredients 

INNER JOIN producthasingredients ON ingredients.id = producthasingredients.id_ingredient 
INNER JOIN product ON producthasingredients.id_product=product.id
INNER JOIN orderhasproducts ON product.id=orderhasproducts.id_product 
WHERE orderhasproducts.id_order=15 
ORDER BY ingredients.id
```

here are some more example info:

```
producthasingredients.id_ingredient = 200;
producthasingredients.quantity = 10;
producthasingredients.id_product =100    

product.id=100    
product.quantity = 5;

orderhasproducts.id_product = 100;
orderhasproducts.numofproducts = 5
```

That means that product 100 has 5 Liters and has 10% of ingredient 200.
In order we have 5 products (id 100)

More sample data:

lets say we have 2 products in database cocacola and sprite
cocacola ingredients are: sugar (10%), water(80%), cocacolaingredient(10%) and bottle has 1 Liter.

sprite ingredients are: sugar (20%), water(70%), spritegredient(10%) and bottle has 1 Liter.

user place order: 10 bottles of cola, 10 bottles of sprite
query should produce (in yellow):
[please check that image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhcTX.png)

**UPDATE**

```
following query:

        SELECT ingredients.name AS ingredientName, 
ingredients.id AS ingredientId, 
product.id AS productId, product.name AS productName,

        (producthasingredients.quantity * product.quantity / 100) AS ingredientQuantity

FROM ingredients 

INNER JOIN producthasingredients ON ingredients.id = producthasingredients.id_ingredient 
INNER JOIN product ON product.id=producthasingredients.id_product 
INNER JOIN orderhasproducts WHERE id_order=16
```

gives me output

```
ingredientName                ingredientId  productId  productName        iQuant  
----------------------------  ------------  ---------  -----------------  ------
proszek do drewna                        1          4  płyn do drewna     3.00          
proszek do podłóg                        2          3  płyn do podłóg     2.50         
proszek do szyb                          3          2  płyn do szyb       1.00          
składnik uniwersalny                     4          1  płyn do naczyń     2.00          
składnik uniwersalny                     4          2  płyn do szyb       1.00          
składnik uniwersalny                     4          3  płyn do podłóg     1.00          
proszek do płynu do naczyń               5          1  płyn do naczyń     1.00          
składnik uniwersalny 2                   6          4  płyn do drewna     1.00          
składnik uniwersalny 3                   7          1  płyn do naczyń     0.50          
składnik uniwersalny 3                   7          2  płyn do szyb       0.50
```

now what I need to do is to sum ingredients with the same ID

Comment: Pls provide some sample data, expected output based on the sample data, and the output your query produces on the sample data. Pls also describe what does not work, do not expect us to figure that out as well ourselves.

Comment: The wording of " calculate total number of all ingredients for all products in particular order" is vague. It could be sum of all ingredients across all products or number of ingredients per product.

Comment: What does product.quantity means in ur conception ?

Comment: product.quantity means - ie. in single bottle you have 1 liter of coca cola,

I have created excel and made screen shot of that, so it should help.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the total for each ingredient. I added a division by 1 to convert to decimal beforehand or you'll lose info when dividing by 100:

```
SELECT distinct ingredients.name, 

(SELECT SUM((producthasingredients.quantity/1.0) * (product.quantity/1.0) / 100 * orderhasproducts.numofproducts)
        FROM producthasingredients INNER JOIN product ON product.id= producthasingredients.id_product 
        WHERE ingredients.id=producthasingredients.id_ingredient )AS totalIngredient

FROM ingredients 

INNER JOIN producthasingredients ON ingredients.id = producthasingredients.id_ingredient 
INNER JOIN product ON producthasingredients.id_product=product.id
INNER JOIN orderhasproducts ON product.id=orderhasproducts.id_product 
WHERE orderhasproducts.id_order=15
ORDER BY ingredients.id;
```

Comment: This result error:
Error Code: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    SELECT result.name,SUM(result.totalIngredient) FROM 
(SELECT distinct ingredients.name, (SELECT SUM((producthasingredients.quantity/1.0) * (product.quantity/1.0) / 100 * orderhasproducts.numofproducts) FROM producthasingredients INNER JOIN product ON product.id= producthasingredients.id_product WHERE ingredients.id=producthasingredients.id_ingredient )AS totalIngredient FROM ingredients INNER JOIN producthasingredients ON ingredients.id = producthasingredients.id_ingredient INNER JOIN product ON producthasingredients.id_product=product.id INNER JOIN orderhasproducts ON product.id=orderhasproducts.id_product WHERE orderhasproducts.id_order=1 ORDER BY ingredients.id) as result 
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: nope.. producthasingredients inner join producthasingredients ;)